# How to get the latest value of an Input inside an Event Handler function in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to get and validate the latest value of the text input inside event handler function, but it is showing the previous value.

```
const [mobile, setMobile] = useState('');

const handleMobile=(text)=>{
    setMobile(text);
    console.log(mobile);
    validateMobile();
    shouldShowMobileError();
}

<Input
    value={mobile}
    onChangeText={(text)=>{handleMobile(text)}}
/>
```

[image: mobile input]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating a React component’s state is asynchronous, which means it does not happen immediately.
So you can use `useEffect` hook for this.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(mobile);
}, [mobile]);
```

The resulting code will look like:

```js
const [mobile, setMobile] = useState('');

const handleMobile=(text)=>{
    setMobile(text);
}

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(mobile);
}, [mobile]);

<Input
    value={mobile}
    onChangeText={(text)=>{handleMobile(text)}}
/>
```

Comment: Hi, if i'm going to do validation when the mobile changes, should i use useEffect to replace the handleMobile() function?

Comment: Using the handleMobile you can validate the `text` before using setMobile. If you want to validate after the value of mobile changes, then you need to do it in `useEffect`